# Converting 3-bit binary to Octal using RB0 ext. INT

Tags: interrupts, assembly

I am tasked with converting 3 bit binary number to Octal whenever the rising edge of the RB0 interrupt occurs, that I can do easily, the problem is that it is required to be displayed on a 7-Seg. Display connected to PORTB, I did a look up table but whenever the interrupt occurs, it doesn't reflect the value on the 7-Segment display.

Comment: Anything to help

Comment: Using PIC 16F818

Comment: I think your problem is on line 317. Wait hold on my crystal ball is a bit out of focus ... maybe line 371?
How do you expect anyone to help you if you don't show what you've done?

Comment: Imagine you were tasked with answering this question. What information would you want:- program listing? schematic? which segments actually lit up on the display for each code? We can help you find the error in your design, but only if you show it to us.

Comment: If the interrupt is working, put it aside and debug your conversion part. You might like to read the 3 bits from another port to be able to change the value and convert repeatedly.

Comment: 1. Give us FAR more information of what you have done. 2. Break the problem up into parts: | Write data to the display. Does it appear. Good. | Send a 3 bit binary number to the conversion routine and send the output to the display. Does it display correctly? Make it do so| Successively wite two different numbers to the convert and display routines with a say 1 second pause between. Do the correct alternat numbers appear? Make it so. | Is your interup routine doing what you expect - use the routine to simply toggle the display all on / all off. Does it work? Make it so. || Combine them all.

Answer (score 1):

Give us FAR more information re what you have done.

Until then, break the problem up into parts:

Write data to the display.
Does it appear.
Good.

Send a 3 bit binary number to the conversion routine and send the output to the display.
Does it display correctly?
Make it do so.

Successively write two different numbers to the convert and display routines with a say 1 second pause between.
Do the correct numbers appear alternately?
Make it so.

Is your interupt routine doing what you expect?
Use the routine to simply toggle the display all on / all off.
Does it work?
Make it so.

Combine them all.
It works!

Report back.